# Parse JSON object twice in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have two function `readJSON()` and `readAndParseJSON()`, I'm seeing the issue when calling the function one after another since im parsing it twice(I guess).

How can I unparse or undo the things before calling again. I cant edit readJSON and readAndParseJSON.
`req` is `HttpServletRequest`.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONReaderAndParser.readAndParseJSON(req);
if (jsonObject.get("abc") != null) 
  Boolean abc = Boolean.parseBoolean(jsonObject.get("abc").toString());         
fun(JSONReaderAndParser.readJSON(request),abc);
```

```
public static Object readAndParseJSON(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Object object;

    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        String data = null;
        data = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        jsonString.append(data);

        object = parser.parse(jsonString.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("Server error");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new Exception("bad request");
    }

    if (object == null) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid json");
    }

    return object;
    }

    public static String readJSON(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
    String data = null;
    try {
        data = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        jsonString.append(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    if (data == null) {
        throw new Exception("Parsed object is null");
    }

    return jsonString.toString();
    }
```

getting error:

```
Exception while parsing JSON string: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
```

Comment: You're not parsing the json twice but you're trying to read data from an input stream that has already been consumed. Why are you calling those 2 methods on the same stream anyways? Can you explain the use case? I'd probably go for `readJson()` + `parseJson(String jsonString)`.

Comment: Can't see any reason that you would want to parse it twice. I can't even see a reason why you would still need the raw string. Anyways a solution would be to split readAndParseJSON into readJSON and parseJSON and save the read String in a local variable. The Problem is just that the inputStream can only be read once.

Comment: Its kinda predefined functions used multiple places so I can't edit parseAndReadJSON and readJSON. Thanks for helping me with inputStream clue since it can be read twice. I just parsed and get `abc` value inside fun().